# Dependency injection and delegates c#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, delegates, botframework, ninject

I am trying to add dependency injection in this class, but I am not sure if is possible.

```
[Serializable]
    public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        private Chat _chat;
    private IFixedAnswerService _fixedAnswerService ;

        public RootDialog(IFixedAnswerService fixedAnswerService, Chat chat)    
        {
            _fixedAnswerService = fixedAnswerService;
        }

    public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        if(_chat.channel = "messenger")
        some code.....

        _fixedAnswerService.find(xxxxx);
    }
}
```

Calling this way:

```
Chat chat = new Chat
                    {
                        BotId = new Guid(BotId),
                        ConversationId = 1
                     }


await Bot.Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog(chat));
```

But I dont want to pass IFixedAnswerService as parameter, I only want to pass chat object.

And I am binding IFixedAnswerService like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IFixedAnswerService>().To<FixedAnswerService>();
```

But i am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: First of all, you don't have a constructor for RootDialog that takes a Chat object. Are you aware of that?

Also, `_serviceFixedAnswer` is different from `_fixedAnswerService`... is that intentional?

Comment: Yes I missed chat in the constructor, the point is, I want to send chat, but IFixedAnswerService i dont want to pass, I want ninject to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that this is v3, and my assumption this is an existing bot, not a brand new one (if new, I would suggest going with v4).

You could inject a MakeRoot object that makes the root dialog. But maybe better, inject the FixedAnswerService into the controller and use it in the constructor of RootDialog.
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/v3-sdk-samples/CSharp/intelligence-Zummer/Controllers/MessagesController.cs#L31

Also check out this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819193/injecting-external-dependencies-in-microsoft-bot-framework-dialog-using-autofac/39645446).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give a try